# $f(n) = \Omega(n), g(n) = \mathcal O(n), h(n)= \theta(n) \implies f(n).g(n)+h(n)=\Omega(n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

> Let $f(n) = \Omega(n), g(n) = \mathcal O(n), h(n)= \theta(n) \implies f(n).g(n)+h(n)=\Omega(n)$

We get

$g(n) \leq [n ==h(n)] \leq f(n)$

$f(n).g(n)+h(n) \geq n+n \cdot g(n)$

But problem gives upper bound of g but not lower bound. To get greatest lower bound, i can put $g(n)$'s max value as $n$. Then $f(n).g(n)+h(n) \geq n+n\cdot n = n^2 \geq n$ PLease correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that there is an implicit assumption that $g(n)\geq 0$; without this the statement would not be correct, e.g. by taking $f(n)=h(n)$ and $g(n)=-1$.

With this assumption, we simply have $f(n)g(n)+h(n)\geq h(n)=\Omega(n)$.

(The fact that $f(n)$ and $h(n)$ are positive, at least for $n$ sufficiently large, does follow from the given conditions.)

Incidentally, when you talk about "putting $g(n)$'s greatest value as $n$", don't forget the constant: we only know $g(n)\leq cn$ for some $c>0$ (and $n$ sufficiently large).

Comment: sir, My doubt is why is not the lower bound written as $n^2$ if it is the more tighest value than n

Comment: @Srinivas $\Omega(n^2)$ isn't a lower bound, since $g(n)$ could be $0$.

Comment: sir $\Omega$ means >= right. It means greatest lower bound = $n^2$? i am substituting >=h(n){1+g(n)} with g(n)'s maximum value. It means doesn't n^2 greatest lower bound?

Comment: if some function say $p(n) \geq n \implies [p(n)]^2 \geq n^2$?

Comment: @Srinivas to get a lower bound, you should be using the minimum value of $g(n)$ (which is $0$), not the maximum. Also, $\Omega$ does not mean $\geq$; for example $0.01n=\Omega(n)$.

Comment: thank you. Understood now